# Fork a question

Tags: feature-request, questions

Let's say I've posted a question which is about some problem with CSS. For this question there is no answer because what I want is simply not possible with CSS only.

It would be nice to have a feature which forks a question and there I can add or change the tags (eg. add LESS) and change some details on the question.

Comment: If what you want is not possible, then "What you want is not possible, due to (reasons)" is an answer. There are no unanswerable questions.

Answer (score 12):

Not needed IMO. If you want to ask a new question, ask a new question, and link to the other one for reference.

Answer (score 4):

In version control systems forking is used to copy not just the current revision, but to inherit the history as well. It also saves having to copy many parts.

But copying the revision history of a post is not going to get you anything on Stack Overflow. And there are only *three parts* to copy on a post; the title, the body, and the tags. That's not exactly hard to copy!

Next, I don't think we want to *encourage* wholesale copying only to change a minor detail. Your intentions are fine, but what will happen when you add a 'fork' feature is that people will use it to try and recreate a popular question so they can be popular too. They'll change something minor, and hope they can capture some of the magic *popularity dust*. It is fine to use a question as a basis for your own, but proper use of this is actually quite *rare*.

So, in summary: it is trivial to create a copy of a question manually, there is nothing to gain from copying anything more than the title, body and tags, we don't want to encourage such behaviour, and proper use is not prevalent enough to warrant a special feature.

Comment: I agree, copying the revision history is pointless, but that doesn't mean the rest of the suggestion is without merit.  The issue with manually creating a copy of the question, is that it will probably be incorrectly closed as a duplicate.  If the forking/copying functionality was built into SO, it would be able to give the reviewers a message saying that this question was forked because of reason X, Y or Z.  This could be something similar to the current message on the site of "this question is related to the following" (IIRC).

Comment: @DoctorJones: the likelyhood that the post should be closed anyway is very high; there really are very few reasons to use a wholesale copy as a starting point. Good questions stand on their own.

Comment: Yeah, it depends on how often we'd expect the feature to be needed.  There's no point in developing a new feature, for the very rare circumstance where it'd be genuinely useful.